# Polygons for postcodes in Spain

Tags: data, postal-code, spain

Is there a source (free or paid) for polygons of border coordinates for spanish postcodes?
Google show this borders in google maps, but doesn't provide them.

Comment: I would look at the spanish national survey / statistical authority of spain / institute for geodesy/ ..., but I am not familiar with the spanish government structure.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion til_b, but I did search in the INE (National Institute for Statistics) and IGN (National Institute for Geography) websites and didn't find this information.

Comment: found a wms; see the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **paid** for postal codes for Spain (mapa código postal España)

> Spain and Andorra (mapa código postal España) GfK GeoMarketing offers
>   up-to-date postcode / postal (mapa código postal), administrative
>   (Municipios, Comunidades Autonomas) and topographic digital maps of
>   Spain for use in geographic information systems (GIS) and mapping
>   software.

[image]

Available as:

digital postcode maps for GIS

```
2-digit postcode areas
5-digit postcode areas
```

http://www.gfk-geomarketing.com/en/digital_maps/spain.html

Declaimer: Have in the past used gfk-geomarketing data sets they are good quality but am not associated in anyway with the company.

Answer (score 2):

I only did a quick search but try here:

http://www.mbi-geodata.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=99&Itemid=59

Answer (score 1):

The WMS at http://www.cartociudad.es/wms/CARTOCIUDAD/CARTOCIUDAD?Request=GetCapabilities provides a layer called "CodigoPostal", which seems to contain postcodes. As far as i can see the layer is queryable.

I found this WMS by searching with google for "código postal España inurl:wms".

**I don't know enough spanish to decide whether this service is free/legal/illegal to use.**

The capabilities state

```
<Fees>no conditions apply</Fees>
<AccessConstraints>OtherConstraints. Se permite cualquier uso si se menciona la autoría del IGN del siguiente modo: «© Instituto Geográfico Nacional de España»</AccessConstraints>
```

edit 2022-01-24: The WMS link may be dead, but at http://centrodedescargas.cnig.es/CentroDescargas/buscadorCatalogo.do?codFamilia=02122 there is a download portal of sorts. I still don't know enough spanish to see whether its helpful or not.

Comment: Thank you, til_b, I'm very busy right now with other project issues, but I'll have a look as soon as posible.

Comment: "AccessContraints" means "All uses allowed if authoring by IGN is mentioned as <<© Instituto Geográfico Nacional de España>>"

Answer (score 1):

Check out also this [postal code search engine for Spain](http://www.codigo-postal.info/). I don't know if this is what you need, but this site crosses postal code data with Google Maps, so it must provide the coordinates to generate the maps.

http://www.codigo-postal.info/

Comment: I've also found this other resource from the Madrid city hall: http://www.madrid.org/nomecalles/DescargaBDTCorte.icm You can download a vectorial map of the city with, among other things, the postal codes of the city. Only for Madrid, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove http://www.digiatlas.com/cgi-php/maps_vector.php?kind=postcode

> Geo-referenced maps of the Spanish provinces with 5-digits postalcode
>   areas. Shapefiles and KML. The Shapefile format are associated with
>   their database and ready to incorporate your own data and overlay on
>   SIG applications (Geographic Information Systems). KML is a file
>   format used to display geographic data in an Earth browser such as
>   Google Earth, Google Maps, and Google Maps for mobile.